# Converting a object to json

Tags: javascript

I have an output like this:

```
[ { id: 1,
    username: 'testuser',
    password: 'testpass',
    phone: '+905557664823' }]
```

How can I convert this output to this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "testuser",
            "password": "testpass",
            "phone": "+905557664823"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a string?

Comment: Maybe you just wanna use something like this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Where is this output coming from?  Is that *really* a string, or is it an object?

Comment: It is a object. I edited my question.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = [ { id: 1,
    username: 'testuser',
    password: 'testpass',
    phone: '+905557664823' }];

var output = { result: input};
```

If you really need the quotes, you can convert it to string:

```
var outputString = JSON.stringify(output);
```